# How to sort custom post's category by id from the theme's function.php?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, categories, order, sort

I'm wondering how to sort a custom post's categories in the selection field which I've circled in the screenshot?

[image: my idea is to sort custom post's categories in the selection field which encircled]

And I have the following code which generates category listing

```
 $args=array(
                'class'       => 'select-submit2',
                'hide_empty'  => false,
                'selected'    => $prop_category_selected,
                'name'        => 'prop_category',
                'id'          => 'prop_category_submit',
                'orderby'     => 'NAME',
                'order'       => 'ASC',
                'show_option_none'   => __('None','wpestate'),
                'taxonomy'    => 'property_category',
                'hierarchical'=> true
            );
        wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the dropdown code? Its a widget?

Comment: @DavidLee, I do have access to all the codes, but I don't know specifically which code is the dropdown code. I don't know whether, it's widget or not. But I used the advance search shortcode of theme developer using visual composer. I hope it helps. Thanx

Comment: Need more info to answer

Comment: can you inspect the HTML code, you can see if its a widget of the name there.

Comment: Actually you can sort the categories of any post type in the categories screen under the post menu. Just drag and drop the categories in the order you want them to be. Usually all themes reflect this sorting of categories in the front end.

Comment: @DavidLee - plz see the update question.

Answer (score 1):

In your `wp_dropdown_categories` function call, you are using `'orderby' => 'NAME'`. This argument is case-sensitive, and it should be `'orderby' => 'name'` (all lowercase).

```
$args = array(
    'class'             => 'select-submit2',
    'hide_empty'        => false,
    'selected'          => $prop_category_selected,
    'name'              => 'prop_category',
    'id'                => 'prop_category_submit',
    'orderby'           => 'name', // Corrected to lowercase 'name'
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'show_option_none'  => __('None', 'wpestate'),
    'taxonomy'          => 'property_category',
    'hierarchical'      => true
);

wp_dropdown_categories($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `orderby` to `ID`:

```
            $args=array(
                'class'       => 'select-submit2',
                'hide_empty'  => false,
                'selected'    => $prop_category_selected,
                'name'        => 'prop_category',
                'id'          => 'prop_category_submit',
                'orderby'     => 'ID', //this changed to ID
                'order'       => 'ASC',
                'show_option_none'   => __('None','wpestate'),
                'taxonomy'    => 'property_category',
                'hierarchical'=> true
            );
        wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
```

Comment: thanx for the code, but I want to order it by specific order like ID:- 73, 68 , 72 etc etc.

Comment: `wp_dropdown_categories()` returns an array? can you add the structure to your question please

Comment: the above code, seems to sort the category selections in the ascending order. But I want to order the category selection in specific order using the ID. Does it makes sense? plz bear with me.

Comment: I understand what i want to know is the output of `wp_dropdown_categories()` to see if we can order with that, if its an array we can iterate to re-order it , or if you have it, the code of the function itself, that will help too.

Comment: I didn't understand you. Can u plz give me the code? Millions of thanx

Comment: it is ordering the ID in Ascending order. can you plz help me with the iterate to re-order it.